# C++ Programming : Error when assigning the iterator to vector

Tags: c++, c++11

```
    vector<vector<string> > vvs;
    vector<string> vs;

    vs.push_back("r1-c1");
    vs.push_back("r1-c2");
    vs.push_back("r1-c3");

    vvs.push_back(vs);

    for (vector<vector<string> >::iterator vvsi = vvs.begin(); vvsi != vvs.end(); vvsi++) {
        vector<string> vec_str = *vvsi;
        for (vector<string>::iterator vsi = vec_str.begin(); vsi != vec_str.end(); vsi++) {
            cout << *vsi << ", ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
```

In the above C++ code, to avoid the copy of vector(vector vec_str = *vvsi) i tried the below code

```
vector<string> *vec_str = vvsi.base(); //Working. which (returns a const pointer&)     
vector<string> *vec_str = &(*vvsi); //Working. Assigning the address
```

But

```
vector<string> *vec_str = vvsi; //Error. Not able to assign
```

Error

```
(build error : cannot convert 'std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::iterator to 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >*' in initialization)
```

In a case of integer

```
    int a=10;
    int *b = &a; //working. Assigning address
    int *c = &(*b); //working. Assigning address
    int *d = b; //working. Assigning address
    *c=11;
    std::cout << a<<"\n";
    *d=12;
    std::cout << a<<"\n";
```

In the case of vector, why the build error when assigning (can't able to understand from the C++ iterator documentation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An iterator is not a pointer. It's interface was made to be used as a pointer, but it certainly is not a pointer.

However, if you simply want to iterate through the elements of each vector in the parent vector, there is no need to assign it to a temporary vector or to a pointer, the iterator itself is good enough:

```
for (vector<vector<string> >::iterator vvsi = vvs.begin(); vvsi != vvs.end(); ++vvsi) {
    for (vector<string>::iterator vsi = vvsi->begin(); vsi != vvsi->end(); ++vsi) {
        cout << *vsi << ", ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Also, since you put c++11 as a tag in your question, I assume you might be interested in a more modern expression:

```
for(auto& vst : vvs){
    for(auto& st : vst){
        cout << st << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign the value of an iterator to a pointer. That the iterator points to the same type as the pointer is irrelevant, since [RandomAccessIterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), which are the iterator type of `std::vector`, are not implicitly convertible to pointers.

If you're using c++11, there are simpler ways to go about iterating over a vector of a vector even than @A Hernandez's solution (or any container of containers at that), using the range-for syntax available in c++14:

```
for(auto &&stringVec : vvs){
     for(auto &&str : stringVec){
         cout << str << ", ";
     }
}
cout << '\n';
```

The `&&` here allows binding to temporary containers as well as existing ones, so you can use this syntax with both existing container containers and container containers returned from a function without storing them.